# What is the full form of 'won't you?'

Tags: questions, contractions, tag-questions

In an example sentence like: 'Sit down, won't you?' 
What is the full form of that sentence without contraction? Is it 'Sit down, will you not?' cause we can't say 'Sit down, will not you?'

Comment: Welcome to ELL, xiaoqianqian. That is a good question, but there is already an answer to a very similar question, so I'm going to propose closing this question as a duplicate.